# AndroidResideMenu: how to make not transparent background

Tags: android, animation, menu, background

In my learning process I created a dashboard screen with AndroidResideMenu animation from GitHub SpecialCyCi/AndroidResideMenu.

But I have a problem with transparency. On my screenshots there is a gray or black blurred rectangle. That rectangle is what I don't want to see. There should be a white background instead of that blurred transparent black. That green leather is total background.

PS. the graphics is just for testing and learning. Not beautiful, I know.

[main dashboard showed on fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNbfP.jpg)
[moving on the side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnaCT.jpg)

*DashboardActivity.java*

```
 //ResideMenu
 // attach to current activity;
 resideMenu = new ResideMenu(this);
 resideMenu.setBackground(R.drawable.background);
 resideMenu.attachToActivity(this);

 // create menu items;
 String titles[] = { "Home", "Gallery", "Calendar", "Settings" };
 int icon[] = { R.drawable.run, R.drawable.run, R.drawable.run, R.drawable.run };

 for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++){
     ResideMenuItem item = new ResideMenuItem(this, icon[i], titles[i]);
     final int position = i;
     item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
             switch (position){

             }
         }
     });
     resideMenu.addMenuItem(item,  ResideMenu.DIRECTION_LEFT); // or  ResideMenu.DIRECTION_RIGHT
 }
```

Comment: Please include your code in the question.

Comment: added, thx for info

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding a background color into activity_dashboard.xml 
file

> android:background="@color/white"

problem solved
thx Diego for help